# How to send and receive userdata in notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to send NSMutableDictionary with 4 key-values in notification and want same at receiving side.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject userInfo:(NSDictionary *)aUserInfo;
```

I think you can use the `userInfo` argument